# Can we do LinkedIn profile search just like office 365 outlook do using LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am working on one java-script app in which i will show employees of my ORG with LinkedIn button just like O365 Outlook and after click on that button LinkedIn matched (matched with the name of employee) profile will show.

I am trying this API "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people"
but it is giving me error "Not enough permissions to access: GET /people" even i am providing access token.

Can some one help me on this.

Thanks,
Dinesh

Comment: You should provide your methodology for acquiring the access token and exactly how you're sending your http. it is not really possible to replicate your issue with the current info.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I followed this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context) to get access token and my request is https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people?q=vanityName&vanityName=dinesh%20negi

Comment: LinkedIn allowing to do people search via it's api? 
like it was in V1 http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id))?first-name=bill&last-name=gates